# Making time conditions

Tags: stata

I'm working in Stata 14 and I have a time string variable.
I want to change it so that I can make operations conditional on time.
For example, I want to know the average of a variable if the observation was taken before noon.

```
sum price if time<12:00
```

Is that possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Trying this would be instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your times run from `"00:00"` to `"23:59"` then

```
... if time < "12:00"
```

will do what you want as `<` for strings uses alphanumeric order and times before and after noon will fall as you want them. The double quotes (which you omit) are essential for a literal string value.

Warning: I have seen data with times before 1 a.m. represented as `"24:00"` to `"24:59"`. Such times would certainly mess up everything.

For most purposes, you would be on safer ground converting your string times to a numeric date-time variable, as explained prominently in `help datetime`.